# Is this join possible in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure how else to ask the question, so I will give an example, to see if this is possible with SQL.

Let's say a customer visits a store, and a System creates a VisitID. Then he places an Order in a table of Orders, linked to the VisitID. Then he fills in a Shipping Form, in a table of ShippingForms, linked to the Visit ID. Then the system generates a Receipt, in a table of ReceiptForms, linked to the VisitID. Then he fills in a Return Form, in a table of ReturnForms, linked to the VisitID.

So, is there a way to query the system to show for a VisitID there is/isn't an Orders record, Shipping Form record, Receipt record, Return record? This would be handy in a DBGrid to show all the activities of the customer on that VisitID. Each table (Orders, ShippingForm, ReceiptForm, ReturnForm, etc.) is of a different structure and different fields, but linked by the Visit ID, and may be present or not present, or may have several Orders during that VisitID.

So -- Select Orders, ShippingForm, ReceiptForm, ReturnForm where VisitID=x.
so I could present the information in a grid such as:

```
{
VisitID 2315
      OrderID 1256
      OrderID 1257
      OrderID 1258
      ReceiptID 5124
      ReceiptID 5125
      ReceiptID 5126
      ShippingID 99023
      ReturnID 582812
}
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You should always tag SQL questions with the DBMS you are asking them for.

Comment: i am using MySQL, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Visits that do not have records in all tables:

```
Select *
  from Visits v -- visit always exists
  left join Orders o on o.visitId = v.visitId
  left join ShippingForm s on s.visitId = v.visitId 
  left join ReceiptForm r on r.visitId = v.visitId
  left join ReturnForm rf on fr.visitId - v.visitId
 where v.VisitID=x
   and (o.visitId is null or s.visitId is null or r.visitId is null or fr.visitId is null ) -- it is null when record does not exist
```

Comment: Thank you, OjtamOjtam; is there a way to list the results using grouping so that each result is a new line as in the example?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `UNION ALL`:

```
select visitid, type, id
from
(
  select visitid, 'visit' as type, 1 as sortkey, null as id from visits
  union all
  select visitid, 'order' as type, 2 as sortkey, orderid as id from orders
  union all
  select visitid, 'receipt' as type, 3 as sortkey, receiptid as id from receipts
  union all
  select visitid, 'shipping' as type, 4 as sortkey, shippingid as id from shippings
  union all
  select visitid, 'return' as type, 5 as sortkey, returnid as id from returns
) data
order by visitid, sortkey;
```

Or you may want string aggregation. This is DBMS dependent and you haven't mentioned your DBMS. This is for MySQL:

```
select
  visitid,
  ord.ids as orderids,
  rcp.ids as receiptids,
  shp.ids as shippingids,
  ret.ids as returnids
from visits v
left join
  (select visitid, group_concat(orderid) as ids from orders group by visitid) ord
    using (visitid)
left join
  (select visitid, group_concat(receiptid) as ids from receipts group by visitid) rcp
    using (visitid)
left join
  (select visitid, group_concat(shippingid) as ids from shippings group by visitid) shp
    using (visitid)
left join
  (select visitid, group_concat(returnid) as ids from returns group by visitid) ret
    using (visitid)
order by visitid;
```

Comment: *"This is for MySQL:"* `GROUP_CONCAT` is also supported by Google BigQuery and SQLite that i know off..  But i have doubts about using `select visitid, group_concat(<column>) .. `without `GROUP BY  visitid` as a aggregated column and a non aggregated column can't be mixed

Comment: Thank you @Raymond Nijland. You are right of course, I forgot the `GROUP BY` clauses when typing the subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, you have allowed me to answer the question. For my purposes, I combined the results to make this sol

```
select 
   OrderID as FormID,
   1 as FormType,
   'Order ID' as FormTitle
   from Orders O,  Visits V where (O.VisitID=V.VisitID) and (V.VisitID=112)
union all
   ShippingID as FormID,
   2 as FormType,
   'Shipping ID' as FormTitle
   from Shipping S,  Visits V where (S.VisitID=V.VisitID) and (V.VisitID=112)
```

etc.
so now have a line by line table for VisitID=112:

```
FormID        FormType       FormTitle
23            1              Order ID
26            1              Order ID
28            1              Order ID
342           2              Shipping ID
343           2              Shipping ID
367           2              Shipping ID
```

Comment: I'm glad you've found an answer to your problem. You shouldn't use comma-separated joins though. There were made redundant in standard SQL 1992. It's considered bad style to use them still. And you may want to add an `ORDER BY` clause, as to ensure you get orders first and shippings second. `UNION ALL` alone does not guarantee an order. You need `ORDER BY` to guarantee an ordered result.